# A proud coward. Is there a word for that sort of person?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, expressions

Someone who is proud of himself, his moral values etc. however who is a coward in his general approach, related to anything in which he could get involved with, since he avoids most situations.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if anyone will come up with a single word. For me, it seems like *coward* and *proud* don't go together well enough (so I'd need at least two words).

Comment: I don't know. It seemed to me they go together well. Someone with an attitude (of being proud), however, who is empty inside (kind of), just like a coward.

Comment: That would sound like a *hypocrite* to me, but I think it's not what you're looking for.

Comment: There is probably a very long greco-roman word for something like that, can you give more context, are you writing something and need some good words for it?

Answer (score 1):

American English (not familiar with usage elsewhere in the world) tends to assume that someone who is proud and a coward will also brag a lot, talking about how great they are to make themselves sound better than the are. There is a connotation that these people are overly proud of themselves, and an implication that they are cowards, because only a coward would need to boast about skill/experience/bravery they don't have. So there is no word that means "Proud coward" but a lot of words or phrases that would give that meaning in context.

- braggadocious (adj from braggadocio)--boastful but hiding weakness
- Blusterer--someone who 'talks big' but never does anything

Common phrases include:

- he has a big ego but nothing to back it up
- she's full of false pride
- he's all talk
- she's nothing but hot air